# Error while constructing date

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have such code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "day=%d, month=%d, year=%s", day, month, year);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.clear();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

Log.i(TAG, "Date is parsed to %tF", c.getTime(), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

And this is log I get when executing:

```
day=11, month=11, year=1985
Date is parsed to 1985-12-10
```

Why not 1985-12-11? It works correct for some dates or in debug mode. But why it is not always working?

I also have similar issues when working with Date and when parsing dates from String via SimpleDateFormat

EDIT: Other examples of this code executing:

```
day=1, month=0, year=2012
Date is parsed to 2012-01-01

day=25, month=11, year=2011
Date is parsed to 2011-12-25

day=4, month=10, year=1979
Date is parsed to 1979-11-03

day=3, month=11, year=1984
Date is parsed to 1984-12-02
```

day, month and year can't be changed from other threads.

Comment: Could you show where your year, month, and day variables are initialized?

Comment: They are initialized above. It doesn't matter. They are int values and their values are logged

Comment: Dont tell me it doesn't matter. Of course it matters when you're getting unexpected output.

Comment: Are `day`, `month` and `year` changed by other threads? You said it works for some dates?! For what dates it works and for what dates not? Maybe we'll be able to see where your issue belongs to then.

Comment: @darja im confused. What's the problem? Months are 0-based as mentioned!

Comment: @LuxuryMode Read carefully. These are examples. Some of them work as expected and some not. It is not about months being 0-based, it is about DAY_OF_MONTH it seems sometimes to be 0-based and sometimes 1-based, but it should always should be 1-based.

Comment: Please debug your code and tell us what Calendar instance is internally used when you call `Calendar.getInstance()`. You should debug `Calendar.createCalendar()`. I realized that the BuddhistCalendar returns your output for some some dates (except the year). Which locale is returned for `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` on your system?

Comment: Is your issue fixed when you use explicitly `new GregorianCalendar()` instead of `Calendar.getInstance()`?

Comment: Do you create the dates and print them on the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. It seems to be some Android devices issue. It has appeared in 3 of 5 devices. I have fixed it by specifying time.

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a time zone issue?

Comment: It is possible daylight saving time issue, not timezone. It explains something but not why Dec, 25 is init correctly but Dec, 3 is not.

Answer (score 1):

The month in Calendar is zero based. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

I suggest you read this: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/gregoriancalendar.html

If you can, it's actually easier and less bug prone to use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) - it has a much neater and safer API.

Comment: It ain't that nice to vote down an answer, even if it's incomplete. I didn't see the day-of-month issue

Comment: @Eran I did not vote down, but this is not an answer to the question asked here. If you read the question carefully then it is neither an incomplete nor a complete answer. OP is obviously not irritated by month at all. OP is just confused about day of month. But +1 for mentioning joda-time ...

Answer (score 1):

Month is 0-11 and day starts with 1.

Month

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

Day

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH

Edit:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.clear();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1985);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 11);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String strdate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println(strdate);
```

Output:

```
12/11/1985
```

Comment: @darja because you're not doing it right. Do it like vanathi and you've got it.

Comment: I don't need formatting. I need correct values. This code don't work either.

Comment: @darja If the above code doesn't work, please provide some more information.

Comment: @darja I expected you have same issues with this one here since it is basically the same code as yours. Please see my comments about additional infos you can provide. Does it make a difference when you explicitly use `new GregorianCalendar()` instead of `Calendar.getInstance()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
        new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
Log.v("the date is:", simepleDateFormat.format(c.getTime());
```